# the flu VS a flu

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

Here's the situation:

> I have **a** flu.

vs

> I have **the** flu.

I saw some lesson on website about the vocabulary of illnesses.

> Illnesses that use the article -the: 
>   1.flu 
>   2.hiccups 
>   3.measles

but some on website say I have a flu. so, I'm confused about the article for flu.

Should I use **the** or **a** for flu?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Native speakers catch *the* flu at *the* library and then they go to *the* doctor.    It is idiomatic to use the definite article with the ubiquitous and the universal. Once they're well, they can take a trip to *the* beach.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use **a** because **flu is an uncountable noun**.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**flu**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flu) noun [ U ]

> a common infectious illness that causes fever and headache:
>
> *a flu virus 
> to catch/get/have (the) flu*

U - means **uncountable**. You can have more or less flu but you can't have a flu or two flus. Also notice that the example given indicate the use of **the**.

More info about countable vs uncountable, [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-nouns/nouns-countable-and-uncountable).

EDITED: userr2684291 pointed that *The flu is used in AmE, while flu or occasionally the flu (somewhat old-fashioned) in BrE*

Comment: @userr2684291 Edited to include your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@RubioRic's answer is correct to a degree. Most people colloquially refer to the illness as "*the* flu", however as you can see from the dictionary quotation he cites you can refer to "**a** flu virus". It would be medically incorrect to say "the flu virus" unless you had already defined a specific virus that you were speaking about. It is too simplistic to say that "the" should go before "flu" and never "a".

There are many different strains of flu (or *influenza* to use its proper name) and these are caused by distinct *influenza viruses*. As these viruses *are* countable then these *would* be referred to as "**a** flu virus" or "**an** influenza virus".

It is also common to omit "the" altogether and simply say:

> I have flu.

The British [National Health Service page](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/flu/) on flu uses *both* "the flu" and simply "flu" in the same article, but with a clear bias towards the latter:

> "Flu is very infectious.."
>   "GPs don't recommend antibiotics for flu.."
>   "How to treat flu yourself"

It does contain one use of:

> "The flu vaccine..."

but this is referring to *the* vaccine, not *the* flu.

And with specific *new* strains of flu being diagnosed in recent years these are sometimes referred to by their proper names, even outside the medical profession, such as H1N1 (commonly referred to as *swine flu*) or "bird flu". Interestingly these are never referred to as "*the swine flu*".

The use of "the" when referring to an illness is somewhat of a legacy and not always used. You don't hear people say "I have *the* headache" - we say "**a** headache" despite the fact we only have one head. Neither do you hear people speak of (relatively) recently diagnosed conditions this way, such as "the AIDS" (not correctly used to my knowledge). It tends to be restricted to diseases that were historically described that way for example *the pox* (an archaic term for *syphilis* that dates from late middle English but was still commonly used as late as the 1970s in British English), or even *the plague*.

Comment: i would say that that is because viruses are countable (virus
noun [ C ]), and flu are a subset of them.

Comment: The word karkinos, Greek for 'crab', was first used to describe the disease by Hippocrates, so 'the 'flu' is newer than cancer ('influenza' came into English in the 18th century, but 'the flu' is a later anglicization). Lack of an article might be due to our word 'cancer' coming from the Latin; the few diseases that I can think of that do have an article tend not to be Latin terms but English coinings or anglicizations - 'the flu' vs 'influenza', 'the cramps' vs 'dysmenorrhea', 'the squits' vs 'diarrhoea', 'the bends' vs 'decompression sickness'.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Well Pete, there are certainly those early names of conditions that we now believe were likely describing cancer. But we don't use those names. If we did, perhaps we would call cancer *the crab*. Unless you can cite an example of a modern diagnosis which we refer to using *the*, my point stands. But to make you happy I'll change "the cancer" to "the AIDS".

Comment: @WendyG You're correct. In *a/the flu virus*, *a/the* attaches itself to *flu virus*, not *flu*. It's kind of pointless to discuss that because *a/the* can in this way *be used with any noun* (with the noun in question being used as a modifier).

Comment: Native AmEn speaker here, and I've *never* heard the phrase "I have flu" before. (Though just seeing in RubioRic's answer that that phrase is more common in BrEn.)

Comment: @DavidK Native British English here. You surprise me because if anything Americans usually say "I'm sick", when we say a more wordy "I don't feel well" or "I feel ill". Our national health service has a page on flu which uses *both* "the flu" and simply "flu" in the same article. https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/flu/

Comment: @DavidK I have added several of the quotations from the NHS website to my answer.

Comment: @Astralbee I have already done so - both 'the bends' is from 1894 and 'the flu' is earlier C19th, well into the modern era.

Comment: @PeteKirkham So, both examples more than 100 years old? Is that modern? Don't think so. Apparently flu symptoms were described by Hippocrates circa 400BCE. And "the bends" (great example for proving my point") is also archaic as the modern term is *decompression sickness*. You know, this seems like an argument for argument's sake. I haven't claimed that *all* ancient epidemics have "the", but the majority of examples *are* archaic and there are *no* truly modern diseases referred to that way.

Comment: @Astralbee modern English starts at C17th, so both count in linguistic terms. If you instead you mean recent, formal medical terms rather than language, there are very few newly discovered diseases that have been around long enough to have common English names. But obviously your mind is made up, so let's leave it here.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Nonsense. Lyme disease, diagnosed in 1975 and named after the town it was first found in. Norovirus, diagnosed in 1972 and named after **Nor**walk **O**hio where the first outbreak occurred. Ebola - 1976, named for the Ebola river. All common English names, and none of them "the".

Comment: @Astralbee indeed, not all medical terms for diseases derived from English have 'the', and I don't know what the common names of those diseases were, if any. But the light I was trying to shed isn't worth a protracted argument.